# Using configuration specification in VHDL/ModelSim

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm trying to use a VHDL configuration specification to pre-set

This should be possible, as shown in IEEE1076-2008, section 7.3.2.1, which gives the following example:

```
entity AND_GATE is
    generic (I1toO, I2toO: DELAY_LENGTH := 4 ns);
    port (I1, I2: in BIT; O: out BIT);
end entity AND_GATE;

entity XOR_GATE is
    generic (I1toO, I2toO: DELAY_LENGTH := 4 ns);
    port (I1, I2: in BIT; O: out BIT);
end entity XOR_GATE;

package MY_GATES is
    component AND_GATE is
        generic (I1toO, I2toO: DELAY_LENGTH := 4 ns);
        port (I1, I2: in BIT; O: out BIT);
    end component AND_GATE;
    component XOR_GATE is
        generic (I1toO, I2toO: DELAY_LENGTH := 4 ns);
        port (I1, I2: in BIT; O: out BIT);
    end component XOR_GATE;
end package MY_GATES;

entity Half_Adder is
    port (X, Y: in BIT; Sum, Carry: out BIT);
end entity Half_Adder;

use WORK.MY_GATES.all;

architecture Structure of Half_Adder is
    for L1: XOR_GATE use
        entity WORK.XOR_GATE(Behavior) -- The primary binding
            generic map (3 ns, 3 ns) -- indication for instance L1.
            port map (I1 => I1, I2 => I2, O => O);
    for L2: AND_GATE use
        entity WORK.AND_GATE(Behavior) -- The primary binding
            generic map (3 ns, 4 ns) -- indication for instance L2.
            port map (I1, open, O);
begin
    L1: XOR_GATE port map (X, Y, Sum);
    L2: AND_GATE port map (X, Y, Carry);
end architecture Structure;

use WORK.GLOBAL_SIGNALS.all;

configuration Different of Half_Adder is
    for Structure
        for L1: XOR_GATE
            generic map (2.9 ns, 3.6 ns); -- The incremental binding
        end for; -- indication of L1; rebinds its generics.
        for L2: AND_GATE
            generic map (2.8 ns, 3.25 ns) -- The incremental binding
            port map (I2 => Tied_High); -- indication of L2; rebinds
        end for; -- its generics and binds its open port.
    end for;
end configuration Different;
```

Even If I add the package missing from the example myself

```
package GLOBAL_SIGNALS is
    constant Tied_High : bit := '1';
end package GLOBAL_SIGNALS;
```

Elaboration is still failing in Modelsim.

> Error: [...]/half_adder.vhd(36): (vcom-1035) Formal port "I2" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.

Caused by the line

```
port map (I1, open, O);
```

Which already seems to indicate that Modelsim doesn't properly support these configuration statements.

I would like to use this configuration specifications to ease my design entry.

Example:

```
entity comp is
    generic(step : time; defined: boolean);
    port(clk, data : in bit);
end entity;

entity e is end entity e;

architecture a of e is
    component comp is
        generic(step : time; defined: boolean);
        port(clk, data : in bit);
    end component;
    
    signal clk1, clk2 : bit;
    
    for a : comp use
        entity work.comp
            generic map(step => 1 ns)
            port map(clk => clk1);
    for b : comp use
        entity work.comp
            generic map(step => 100 ns)
            port map(clk => clk2);
    for all : comp use
        entity work.comp
            generic map(defined => true);

    signal sig_a, sig_b : bit;
    
begin
    a: comp
        port map(data => sig_a);

    b_gen : for i in 0 to 2 generate
        b: comp
            port map(data => sig_b);
    end generate;
end architecture;
```

This code throws a large number of errors:

> Error: [...]/e.vhd(19): (vcom-1031) Formal generic "defined" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(19): (vcom-1035) Formal port "data" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(23): (vcom-1031) Formal generic "defined" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(23): (vcom-1035) Formal port "data" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(26): (vcom-1031) Formal generic "step" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(24): ALL configuration specification for component "comp" attempts to re-bind instances already bound.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(24): ALL configuration specification for component "comp" attempts to re-bind instances already bound.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(32): (vcom-1031) Formal generic "step" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(32): (vcom-1031) Formal generic "defined" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(32): (vcom-1035) Formal port "clk" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(36): (vcom-1031) Formal generic "step" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(36): (vcom-1031) Formal generic "defined" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(36): (vcom-1035) Formal port "clk" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.
>
> Warning: [...]/e.vhd(24): (vcom-1263) Configuration specification "all : comp" applies to no component instantiation statements.
>
> Error: [...]/e.vhd(20): No statement with label "b" was found.

So it seems this is not the supported way to use configuration specifications. Too bad, because it would ease my design entry.

I this just a Modelsim bug, or will configurations specifications never help with these default bindings this way?

Comment: Configuration specifications in configuration declarations can be very powerful - they'd require no change in the original design description. For instance you could substitute entities from one library with another and provide an interface allowing the use of different actual names. An example of this would be using a different vendor's cell library. That you have no use for it in part because synthesis vendors don't support configuration declarations seeing it as zero sum competition while they can be used for verification in test benches for say different levels of abstraction.

Comment: As noted in the comment to the answer I2 of L2: AND_GATE's port map is Tied_High, a signal from a non-provided package global_signals describes as found in library work by the use clause. It would be a signal in the package of type bit with a default value of '1'.

Comment: @user1155120 wow, you even deleted your answer and voted close. FYI: I was adding more information to my question to clarify my points. I found this necessary, because in your answer you were telling me things I already know. To me that means I need to change my question, as it is not clear to you what I want to know. It still isn't, it seems.

Comment: Your question consist of "But why does Modelsim not accept my configuration spec.?" which is what the answer addressed. What's all the edits? Seems you just want a venue to complain about the standard (and I'm not association with P1076).

Comment: My questions are serious. first: is there a way to do what I want, using configurations. second: are configurations not properly implemented in modelsim.

Comment: And by moving the configuration does not 'fix' the code. And apart from that, moving it would surpass my wish of keeping configurations ordered together. And I wouldn't be able to use the `for all` conf. I set in the architecture.

Comment: In a configuration, the formals are that of the entity.   In a component instance, the formals are that of the component.   Without a configuration, component generics and ports map to entity generics and ports that have the same name. In your incremental mapping, if you leave an entity port open, it is disconnected.   Hence, rather than open, you need to associate the component port I2 to the entity port I2.    Since most do not understand this, I recommend that you never initialize generics on the entity - that way you at least get an error rather than an unexpected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has changed and so has this answer.

**Elaboration is still failing in Modelsim.**

> Error: [...]/half_adder.vhd(36): (vcom-1035) Formal port "I2" has OPEN or no actual associated with it.

**Caused by the line**

```
port map (I1, open, O);
```

**Which already seems to indicate that Modelsim doesn't properly support these configuration statements.**

There is no 'properly' that can be applied to your conclusion, which isn't supported by the VHDL standard.

The error appears to have been caused by an attempt to elaborate `Half_Adder` when I2 is not bound. The configuration specification associates I2 with `open`, which is not allowed.

If you create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
-- IEEE Std 1076-1993 5.2.1 Binding Indication (example)
-- -2008 7.3.2.1

package global_signals is   -- THIS PACKAGE MISSING IN THE EXAMPLE
    signal Tied_High:   bit := '1';
end package;

entity AND_GATE is           -- ADDED entity and architecture
    generic (I1toO, I2toO: DELAY_LENGTH := 4 ns);
    port        (I1, I2: in BIT;   O: out BIT);
end entity AND_GATE;

architecture Behavior of AND_GATE is  -- ADDED
    signal In1, In2:    BIT;
begin
    In1 <= I1 after I1toO;
    In2 <= I2 after I2toO;

    O <= In1 and In2;

    process
    begin
        report
            LF & HT & "I1to0 = " & time'image(I1toO) &
            LF & HT & "I2to0 = " & time'image(I2toO);
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture Behavior;

entity XOR_GATE is            -- ADDED entity and architecture
    generic (I1toO, I2toO : DELAY_LENGTH := 4 ns);
    port        (I1, I2: in BIT;    O : out BIT);
end entity XOR_GATE;

architecture Behavior of XOR_GATE is  -- ADDED
    signal In1, In2:    BIT;
begin
    In1 <= I1 after I1toO;
    In2 <= I2 after I2toO;

    O <= In1 xor In2;

    process
    begin
        report
            LF & HT & "I1to0 = " & time'image(I1toO) &
            LF & HT & "I2to0 = " & time'image(I2toO);
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture Behavior;

package MY_GATES is
   component AND_GATE is
      generic  (I1toO, I2toO: DELAY_LENGTH := 4 ns);
      port       (I1, I2: in BIT;   O: out BIT);
   end component AND_GATE;

   component XOR_GATE is
      generic  (I1toO, I2toO: DELAY_LENGTH := 4 ns);
      port       (I1, I2: in BIT;   O : out BIT);
   end component XOR_GATE;
end package MY_GATES;

entity Half_Adder is
    port    (X, Y: in BIT;
               Sum, Carry: out BIT);
end entity Half_Adder;

use WORK.MY_GATES.all;
architecture Structure of Half_Adder is
    signal O:   bit;            -- Added
    for L1: XOR_GATE use
        entity WORK.XOR_GATE(Behavior)      --  The primary binding indication
             generic map (3 ns, 3 ns)       --  for instance L1.
             port map (I1 => I1, I2 => I2, O => O);

    for L2: AND_GATE use
        entity WORK.AND_GATE(Behavior)      --  The primary binding indication
             -- generic map (3 ns, 4 ns)       --  for instance L2.
             port map (I1, open, O);

begin
    L1: XOR_GATE    port map (X, Y, Sum);
    L2: AND_GATE    port map (X, Y, Carry);
end architecture Structure;

use WORK.GLOBAL_SIGNALS.all;

configuration Different of Half_Adder is
    for Structure
        for L1: XOR_GATE
            generic map (2.9 ns, 3.6 ns); --  The  incremental binding
        end for;               --  indication of L1; rebinds its generics.

        for L2: AND_GATE
            generic map (2.8 ns, 3.25 ns)  -- The incremental binding
            port map (I2 => Tied_High); -- indication L2; rebinds its generics
        end for;                          -- and binds its open port.
    end for;
end configuration Different;
```

in this case all in one design file it analyzes, elaborates and simulates:

> ghdl -a Half_Adder.vhdl
>   ghdl -e different
>   ghdl -r different
>       Half_Adder.vhdl:44:9:@0ms:(report note):
>         I1to0 = 2900000 fs
>         I2to0 = 3600000 fs
>       Half_Adder.vhdl:22:9:@0ms:(report note):
>         I1to0 = 2800000 fs
>         I2to0 = 3250000 fs

while demonstrating the incremental binding expressed in the code functions properly.

Note this requires the a ghdl implementation built from source code containing a recent Github commit.

Commit  : 9e0cf4af3cf2141002b37db9803c15afec8ea2f4 [9e0cf4a]
Parents : b801510561
Author  : Tristan Gingold 
Date    : October 30, 2017 at 7:19:41 AM GMT+13

Analyzing, elaborating and running the above Half_Adder requires a ghdl built from the Github repository after October 30, 2017, the ability to incrementally bind accidentally lost in a change to how semantic analysis was applied, recently restored. The capability will be in ghdl-0.35 when released.

No one noticed the lack for a period of a couple of years. The feature is likely less enthusiastically received than the authors of incremental binding might have hoped. You could also note the example in the standard is not complete and additional typo's have shown up in later revisions. The MCVe is now incorporated in ghdl's test suite.

Your second example code (e.vhdl) you generated doesn't provide a configuration declaration.

> **Annex I (Informative) Glossary**
>
> **incremental binding:** A binding indication in a configuration declaration that either reassociates a previously associated local generic constant or that associates a previously unassociated local port is said to *incrementally rebind* the component instance or instances to which the binding indication applies. (7.3.2.1)

How this 'restriction' comes about is a matter of semantic requirements.

An understanding of incremental binding can be garnered from it's authors in the book 'VHDL'92' by Jean-Michel Bergé, Alain Fonkoua, Serge Maginot and Jacques Rouillard. See VHDL'92, 6. Incremental Binding, pages 47 through 56.

(Incremental binding can also be found published in IEEE Std P1076-1992c, and was subsequently incorporated in the IEEE Std 1076-1993 revision).

There are various semantic shortcomings in your second example:

e.vhdl:

```
entity comp is
    generic(step : time; defined: boolean);
    port(clk, data : in bit);
end entity;

entity e is end entity e;

architecture a of e is
    component comp is
        generic(step : time; defined: boolean);
        port(clk, data : in bit);
    end component;

    signal clk1, clk2 : bit;

    for a : comp use                          -- Line 15
        entity work.comp
            generic map(step => 1 ns)
            port map(clk => clk1);
    for b : comp use                          -- Line 20
        entity work.comp
            generic map(step => 100 ns)
            port map(clk => clk2);
    for all : comp use                        -- Line 24
        entity work.comp
            generic map(defined => true);

    signal sig_a, sig_b : bit;

begin
    a: comp                                   -- Line 31
        port map(data => sig_a);

    b_gen : for i in 0 to 2 generate
        b: comp                              -- Line 35
            port map(data => sig_b);
    end generate;
end architecture;
```

in addition to the lack of a configuration declaration, the example demonstrates those shortcomings by the Modelsim errors and warnings as well as ghdl:

> ```
> ghdl -a e.vhdl
> e.vhdl:31:5:error: no actual for constant interface "step"
> e.vhdl:35:9:error: no actual for constant interface "step"
> e.vhdl:20:9:error: no component instantation with label "b"
> e.vhdl:24:5:error: component instance "a" is already bound by a configuration specification
> e.vhdl:16:5:error: (previous is configuration specification)
> ghdl:error: compilation error
> ```

Synthesis tools generally support configuration specifications but not configuration declarations. Incremental binding  is of no real practical use when applied to designs destined for silicon.

Comment: Thank you. Hmm, so that means that I cannot use configurations specifications for different default assignments to components, as  IEEE1076-2008, section 7.3.2.1 seems to indicate (see edit in my question for more elaborate example.) This way I'm actually not seeing the added value of configuration specifications: default assignments can be added in de component declarations and entity/architecture can be selected in instantiation `label: entity work.ent_name(arch_name)`. This way I consider the use of configuration specification very limited. (And quite elaborate when used.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, by having a default binding, you might miss bindings you forgot to specify (which could happen in a large VLSI design). By leaving it open, you would get an error. I want to use the `defined` generic as a check that the configuration was successfully parsed. But it seems I cannot.

Comment: I just tried to run the example from IEEE1076-2008, section 7.3.2.1 in Modelsim (-2008 mode). But it seems Modelsim does not compute. "Formal port "I2" has OPEN or no actual associated with it." at the line of the configuration specification for `L2` in architecture `Structure`. Is Modelsim wrong, or is the example wrong? In any case, it seems the added value of configurations is not considered that high, seeing they didn't put sufficient effort in getting it to work correctly.